# Why do my fields get truncated after the function call?

Tags: go

http://play.golang.org/p/xFBSZta2CL

I have been trying everything for 2 hours now. Going into the main function, we immediately get to line 24-26:

```
prompter.Define(&Field{"name"})
prompter.Define(&Field{"age"})
```

The define function:

```
fmt.Printf("fields: %+v\n", c.fields)
c.fields = append(c.fields, f)
fmt.Printf("fields: %+v\n", c.fields)
```

After the function call, the `c.fields` array is empty again!!! Output:

```
fields: []
fields: [0x1040a120]
fields: []
fields: [0x1040a130]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The Go Programming Language
>
> [Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ)](http://golang.org/doc/faq)
>
> [Should I define methods on values or pointers?](http://golang.org/doc/faq#methods_on_values_or_pointers)
>
> ```
> func (s *MyStruct) pointerMethod() { } // method on pointer
> func (s MyStruct)  valueMethod()   { } // method on value
> ```
>
> For programmers unaccustomed to pointers, the distinction between
>   these two examples can be confusing, but the situation is actually
>   very simple. When defining a method on a type, the receiver (s in the
>   above examples) behaves exactly as if it were an argument to the
>   method. Whether to define the receiver as a value or as a pointer is
>   the same question, then, as whether a function argument should be a
>   value or a pointer. There are several considerations.
>
> First, and most important, does the method need to modify the
>   receiver? If it does, the receiver must be a pointer. (Slices and maps
>   act as references, so their story is a little more subtle, but for
>   instance to change the length of a slice in a method the receiver must
>   still be a pointer.) In the examples above, if pointerMethod modifies
>   the fields of s, the caller will see those changes, but valueMethod is
>   called with a copy of the caller's argument (that's the definition of
>   passing a value), so changes it makes will be invisible to the caller.
>
> By the way, pointer receivers are identical to the situation in Java,
>   although in Java the pointers are hidden under the covers; it's Go's
>   value receivers that are unusual.
>
> Second is the consideration of efficiency. If the receiver is large, a
>   big struct for instance, it will be much cheaper to use a pointer
>   receiver.
>
> Next is consistency. If some of the methods of the type must have
>   pointer receivers, the rest should too, so the method set is
>   consistent regardless of how the type is used. See the section on
>   method sets for details.
>
> For types such as basic types, slices, and small structs, a value
>   receiver is very cheap so unless the semantics of the method requires
>   a pointer, a value receiver is efficient and clear.

In Go, all arguments and return values are passed by value. Receivers are passed by value. Use a pointer receiver to change the value. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Prompter interface {
    Define(f *Field)
}

type Field struct {
    Key string
}

type Provider interface {
    Prompt(Prompter)
}

var providers = []Provider{
    MyProvider{},
}

type MyProvider struct{}

func (p MyProvider) Prompt(prompter Prompter) {
    prompter.Define(&Field{"name"})
    prompter.Define(&Field{"age"})
}

type CliPrompter struct {
    fields []*Field
}

func NewCliPrompter() *CliPrompter {
    return &CliPrompter{
        fields: make([]*Field, 0, 100),
    }
}

func (c *CliPrompter) Define(f *Field) {
    fmt.Printf("fields: %+v\n", c.fields)
    c.fields = append(c.fields, f)
    fmt.Printf("fields: %+v\n", c.fields)
}

func main() {
    providers[0].Prompt(NewCliPrompter())
}
```

Output:

```
fields: []
fields: [0x1040a120]
fields: [0x1040a120]
fields: [0x1040a120 0x1040a130]
```